# Need to make dynamic rows and columns on the basis json in angular

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, angular6

I have JSON from which I need to make row and columns. the grid can be of any type on the basis of JSON.2*4(2 rows 4 columns), 3*5(3 rows and 5 columns)
I just want to know how to iterate these row and columns. initially rows, then rows can have columns and these nested columns can also have rows further

```
This is the updated JSON
grid_template = {
    type: 'grid',
    rows: [
        {
            columns: [
                {
                    identifier: 'c1',
                    hasRows: false,
                    cashBack: {
                        text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                        '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                        '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                        '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                        '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                    },
                    images: { leafBannerId: '', listPageBannerId: '', overlayImage: '' },
                    width: '50%',
                    height: '20%',
                    '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                    '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                },
                {
                    hasRows: true,
                    rows: [
                        {
                            identifier: 'c2',
                            hasColumns: false,
                            cashBack: {
                                text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                                '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                                '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                                '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                                '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                            },
                            images: { leafBannerId: '', listPageBannerId: '', overlayImage: '' },
                            width: '50%',
                            height: '10%',
                            '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                            '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                        },
                        {
                            hasColumns: true, columns: [
                                {
                                    identifier: 'c3',
                                    cashBack: {
                                        text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                                        '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                                        '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                                    },
                                    title: {
                                        text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                                        '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                                        '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                                    },
                                    images: { leafBannerId: '', listPageBannerId: '', overlayImage: '' },
                                    width: '25%',
                                    height: '10%',
                                    '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                                    '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                                },
                                {
                                    identifier: 'c4',
                                    cashBack: {
                                        text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                                        '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                                        '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                                    },
                                    title: {
                                        text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                                        '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                                        '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                                    },
                                    images: { leafBannerId: '', listPageBannerId: '', overlayImage: '' },
                                    width: '25%',
                                    height: '10%',
                                    '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                                    '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                                } ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            columns: [
                {
                    identifier: 'c5',
                    cashBack: { text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '' },
                    title: {
                        text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                        '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                        '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                    },
                    images: {
                        leafBannerId: '', listPageBannerId: '', overlayImage: '',
                        '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                        '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                    },
                    height: '15%',
                    width: '33%',
                    '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                    '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                },
                {
                    identifier: 'c6',
                    cashBack: {
                        text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                        '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                        '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                        '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                        '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                    },
                    images: { leafBannerId: '', listPageBannerId: '', overlayImage: '' },
                    height: '15%',
                    width: '33%',
                    '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                    '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                },
                {
                    identifier: 'c6',
                    cashBack: {
                        text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                        '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                        '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                        '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                        '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                    },
                    images: { leafBannerId: '', listPageBannerId: '', overlayImage: '' },
                    height: '15%',
                    width: '33%',
                    '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                    '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            columns: [
                {
                    identifier: 'c7',
                    cashBack: {
                        text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                        '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                        '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: '', image: '', height: '', width: '',
                        '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                        '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                    },
                    images: { leafBannerId: '', listPageBannerId: '', overlayImage: '' },
                    view_all: '',
                    height: '10%',
                    width: '100%',
                    '2X': { width: '200px', height: '400px' },
                    '3X': { width: '300px', height: '600px' },
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Is that JSON correct? It appears to have some issues. Please provide the structure of the object instead of values.

Comment: In json , row and columns tag are in any number of times ?

Comment: Is this fix json ?

Comment: hi, i  updated the json